# Why was Liandrin Guirale about to be punished by the Amyrlin Seat?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, the-wheel-of-time-2021

In the Wheel of Time series, I was confused about what went on when the troupe that brought Logain Ablar to Tar Valon reported to the Amyrlin Seat. To recap

> Logain was a powerful channeler. So powerful he needed two Aes Sedai to keep him under wraps. He eventually breaks free and kills Kerene Nagashi. As a result, the other Aes Sedai link with Liandrin and gentle him on the spot.

Amyrlin Seat seems displeased at this and states that she'll consider an appropriate punishment for that. It's implied there are some politics there, but nothing is ever explored because

> Liandrin shifts the spotlight to Morraine

Why was Liandrin about to be punished for what seemed like a defensive act?

Comment: In the books it is Tower Law that the man has to be taken to the tower to be gentled (https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Severing, but if time I'll see if I can find a better reference). There is recent history why the Amyrlin will want this particular law to be especially respected.

Comment: And *especially* respected by the members of the Red Ajah

Comment: @IanBush That linked page is a minefield of major full series spoilers. Please don’t suggest stuff like that to new show-watchers without at least a fair warning.

Comment: There is no explanation in canon since in the books, Logain _is_ brought to Tar Valon to be gentled there. Also in the books I believe you'd need at least 7 Aes Sedai to guarantee that someone stays shielded 24/7, though those who actively monitor the shield do so more effectively. Also in the books, there are _lots_ of undercurrents and plots going on in the background here (which would be major spoilers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is apparently a significant difference between the books and the show here, since in the books, Logain *is* brought to Tar Valon and gentled there. He doesn't break free, although he kills several Aes Sedai before they capture him.

Supposedly according to Tower Law, all male channellers must be brought to the White Tower to be gentled there. There's no particular practical reason for this, as a full circle of thirteen Aes Sedai can perform the required ritual anywhere. It does however seem custom that *angreal* and *sa'angreal* are often used when performing such important rituals and the Tower is reluctant to let such valuable artefacts leave the Tower area (I don't recall if a *sa'angreal* was actually used when Logain was gentled though, since it happens "off stage" in the books).

Between the lines, there is more to this though. The White Tower propaganda goes like "only Aes Sedai can save you from False Dragons", so it is in the White Tower's best interest to make a big show out of capturing one, parading a captured False Dragon for everyone to see, ruler and commoner all alike. This happens in the books where Logain is brought for display on a parade through Caemlyn. Aes Sedai are disliked in many parts of the world, but even in countries where they are, it is still recognized that Aes Sedai are necessary for putting a stop to False Dragons.

In reality, channellers are mortals just like anyone else and could as well be killed by assassins or an arrow etc, even though that might be harder to do than sending for the Aes Sedai.

Once gentled, the male former channeller is kept in Tar Valon in a house arrest of sorts, so the Tower also takes responsibility to act as prison guards. Most False Dragons throughout history have been rebel leaders, so having them loose might be problematic for that reason alone. Most of them couldn't actually channel.

Apart from Aes Sedai propaganda, there are a whole lot of other undercurrents going on here as well. There is a big rivalry between Blue and Red Ajah. All of the most recently appointed Amyrlins have been of Blue Ajah but Red Ajah is actually the largest one in the Tower. For historical reasons, not many Red have been appointed Amyrlin, because the only two who did both failed miserably at their job and were stilled and deposed.

Also, it is well-known among Aes Sedai that Siuan and Moiraine were once close friends and Red Ajah might take any opportunity they get to accuse Siuan of favouritism. For example, Moiraine was allowed to bring an *angreal* with her on her journeys.

In addition, Siuan, Moiraine and Liandrin all have underlying agendas, but explaining those here would be major spoilers and I don't think mentioning them are necessary to answer the question.

Comment: "channellers are mortals just like anyone else" and "Most False Dragons throughout history have been rebel leaders".  Making martyrs out of rebel leaders by killing them probably isn't in the best interest of the White Tower.

Comment: @PeterM It probably depends on the relation between the present ruler of that country and the Tower. For example, not far after Logain was captured, there are others elsewhere in the world also claiming to be the Dragon - one of them in Tear, who distrusts the Tower. Tear was left to deal with that False Dragon themselves, with no aid from Aes Sedai, although in this case he couldn't channel. Whereas 
Saldaea which is very loyal with the Tower did receive help against their False Dragon.

Comment: @PeterM And overall, note that pretty much all countries in the world are feudal societies. The White Tower only cares to have the rulers and important noblemen on their side, they don't care about the common folk at all.

Comment: IIRC in the novella _New Spring_, Siuan and Moraine are present for a prophecy/vision indicating the Dragon is reborn (or will be soon? It has been ages) and the two make it their life's mission to find and guide him.

Comment: I just want to add that Siuan and Morraine specifically say that it is good the sisters have not remembered they where close friends as novices and accepted think that is in The Great Hunt. They have worked to break that link. Also, a very important point here is that Siuan and Morraine have worked to try and find the Dragon. The worst thing that could happen (from their opinion) is the real Dragon to be stilled by accident.

Comment: Tower law requires men to be trialed before gentled. They handed out the punishment without a proper trial. That would most likely open Liandrin for punishment and since she is such a nice person, one can expect that people will jump on this opportunity.

Further, I believe the show will never see a Mazrim Taim but Logain and Taim will actually be the same person in the show.